# style.scss "global" to specific module

Tags: angular, sass

As my Angular 5 application is growing, I have started to move certain similar `component`s into their own `module`.

My question now is: Is it possible to have a file similar to the global `style.scss`, BUT limited in scope to one specific `module` (rather than the whole application)?

i.e. a file **style-mymodule.scss** that applies its styles to all `component`s within the module `mymodule` (but not to any other modules)?

Comment: You can achieve that by importing the `style-mymodule.scss` in all the your component `.scss` files within that module. I am not sure if it's possible to have `style-mymodule.scss` be applied to those components without the imports.

Comment: Alternatively, the `styleUrls` property of the `@Component` decorator takes an array. You could also add the `style-mymodule.scss` there. But again, it involves adding it in each component in the module.

Comment: Thank you Sam for those workaround ideas. I am just thinking that surely mine is a sensible ask that should be supported?

Comment: Yes I do think it's a fair question. I've had that scenario before where I had to create a collection of card components and wanted a common look and feel between those cards. There is a third option I can think of. I will summarise all my options I can think of in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some options, none of which act global solely to your module without some compromise:

## Option 1: SCSS `@import`

Use SCSS `@import` to import the `style-mymodule.scss` in all the your component style sheet within that module.

## Option 2: `@Component` `styleUrls`

The [styleUrls](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#styleUrls) property of the `@Component` decorator takes an array. You could add the `style-mymodule.scss` there.

## Option 3: `angular-cli.json` `styles`

Add `style-mymodule.scss` to the global style sheet in `angular-cli.json`. Within the `style-mymodule.scss`, add all your styles within a parent class:

```
.mymodule {
  // add all the module styles here.
}
```

Then in all the module components use the [host](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host) property within `@Component`:

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {'class': 'mymodule'}
  ...
})
```

Note that since this is not a dynamic class, I used the `host` property instead the often preferred method of using `[@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) for dynamic classes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with option 1 (scss @import) for now, which works fine for me. However, I still would like to see modules coming with their own style.scss file. Where is the best place to turn this into a feature request?

Comment: Perhaps another way of thinking about it, rather than calling it `style-mymodule.scss`, would be to approach it similar to components, i.e. `my.module.scss`.

Comment: The pest place for a feature request would be in the [Angular CLI GitHub Repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues).